# How to align the baselines of a textarea nested in a div

Tags: html, css, alignment, flexbox, text-alignment

I made a table using flex-box and I'm trying to align the baselines of a div and a textarea.  When the textarea is nested inside of a div, I'm unable to align the baselines, but when it's not in the div, they line up as desired.

My constraint is that I need to next the textarea inside a div (or at least in element) because I'm using a component framework that requires that components have a root element (this part isn't important to my question).

So, how can I make the alignment work while still keeping the textarea in a div? This JSFiddle shows my problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/gaor864j/1/

And this is what my structure looks like:

```
<div class="field">
  <div class="field-key">comments:</div>
  <div class="field-value">
    <div id="annoying">
      <textarea class="text-field long-text-field autosize"
                rows="10"
                style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal;">
        This textarea is surrounded by a div (with id #annoying), which is causing the baseline alignment to not work correctly.
      </textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
.field {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.field-key {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 14pt;
  flex-basis: 120px;
}

.field-value {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 14pt;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

textarea, input {
  font-size: 14pt;
}
```

The problem I'm having:

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at. Is this what you're after? https://jsfiddle.net/gaor864j/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! I was hoping to keep the baselines aligned; I forgot to include it in my fiddle, but the padding-top doesn't match between the label and the textbox, so with padding, the alignment is lost.  Do you know if it's possible to fix this? https://jsfiddle.net/gaor864j/3/

Comment: Any reason why you don't apply the same padding to the label? https://jsfiddle.net/gaor864j/4/

Comment: Hmm I could do that.  Mainly because the items in the right column are components that are chosen based on type of data (some are numeric fields, some text fields, and some textareas), and I want these components to be as self contained as possible, as opposed to having to put conditional logic in the parent component that only applies the padding IF the component it's with is a textarea.  So I could do that, I was just trying to see if it was possible not to, given that the purpose of css baseline alignment is similar to what im doing

Comment: The label (`.field-key`) and its sibling (`.field-value`) are flex items and can be aligned with flex properties. The children of `.field-value`, including the content of the textarea, are independent objects. They don't know what the label is doing. I would suggest you make the label and textarea siblings, but I understand that may not be possible in your framework.